# How to lock unwanted hosts out in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, require, host

Each of the following lines in my .htaccess does not lock out the host hst-123-unwanted.tld

```
Require not host unwantedhost.tld
Require not host .unwantedhost.tld
Require not forward-dns unwantedhost.tld
Require not forward-dns .unwantedhost.tld
```

What is wrong?

Thx in advance for your hints.

Additional information to the comment of Bob:

```
<RequireAll>
        Require any granted
        Require not host amazonaws
        Require not host bezeqint
        Require not host colocrossing
        Require not host metajob
        Require not host drive.dn.ua
        Require not host forthnet
        Require not host hinet
        Require not host kievline
        Require not host kyivstar
</RequireAll>
```

will cause this error message:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@my_domain.tld to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache Server at my_domain.tld Port 443

If I change "Require any granted" to "Require all granted" , then the error message disapperars, but the .htaccess does not lock out the unwanted bots.

Answer (score 1):

"require not" cannot be used by itself, it only limits hosts included in a previous require statement.

```
Require any granted
Require not host notwanted.tld
```

Should work.

Comment: Thx for your hint.
I will add more details to my question.